# how do i open only one panel when I use mapping in react for panels

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I have created a panel to map through my users and display their songs below their name. 
The problem im having is that when I click on the {username} it opens all of the accordion panels. I'd like it to only open the accordion for the panel being clicked.

```
                          <PanelGroup accordion id="accordion-example">
                                {this.state.allUsersList.map((user, index) => (
                                    <Panel>
                                        <Panel.Heading>
                                            <Panel.Title toggle >
                                                <Button key={index} className="btn-uvideo">{user.Username}</Button>
                                            </Panel.Title>
                                        </Panel.Heading>
                                        <Panel.Body collapsible>
                                            <ListGroup>
                                                {user.songs.map((song, index) => (
                                                    <ListGroupItem key={index}>
                                                        <Button className="btn-video" onClick={() => this.handleSongChange(song)}>
                                                            <p>{song.SongName}</p>
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </ListGroupItem>
                                                ))}
                                            </ListGroup>
                                        </Panel.Body>
                                    </Panel>
                                ))}
                            </PanelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using **React-Bootstrap**. Looks like you're missing `eventKey`:

> A unique identifier for the Component, the eventKey makes it distinguishable from others in a set. Similar to React's key prop, in that it only needs to be unique amoungst the Components siblings, not globally.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/#panels-accordion

```
<PanelGroup accordion id="accordion-example">
    <Panel eventKey="1">
        ...
    </Panel>
    <Panel eventKey="2">
        ...
    </Panel>
    <Panel eventKey="3">
        ...
    </Panel>
</PanelGroup>
```

Assuming your usernames are unique you can use that value for your `eventKey`:

```
<PanelGroup accordion id="accordion-example">
      {this.state.allUsersList.map((user, index) => (
          <Panel eventKey={user.Username}>
            ...
```

Comment: It won't let me mark this answer as accepted. It might be because I am new to stack overflow and I don't have enough points.

Comment: @MaximusMaxwell You should be able to. "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers